# How to capture the url in mvc-3 for redirection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC-3 application. In my application if user will try to access any view which is decorated as `[Authorize]`, user redirect to the logon view, there user will enter there credentials and redirect to the authorized view (where user wanted to go).

**Problem :** Now if user do not have an account then he will create one using register link. But after creating the new account user will redirect to the home. And i want him to redirect to the authorized view instead of home page. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass url from logon view to register controller, and then pass it around controller until user registers, and then redirect back. Pretty cumbersome.

Comment: thanks, but i want to know how logon view get that `url`. So by this i can use it in other cases also where we do not have logon view with the url

Comment: I suppose (I may look into source later if you want to) that it gets it from `AuthorizationAttribute` (either via `QueryString` or via `TempData`)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that derives from `AuthorizeAttribute`, and override the `OnAuthorization` method. In this method, make the proper authorization checks, and if the user isn't authorized, execute the following code:

```
var route = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", returnUrl = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl });
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(route);
```

Then, in the Login action in you authorization controller, add a parameter named `returnUrl`. After verifying that the user has provided the proper credentials, execute the following:

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
     return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

Make sure to register the class to be used by MVC, by adding this to Application_start in Global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuthorizationAttribute());
```

where `AuthorizationAttribute` is the name of your derived class.

Comment: This doesn't solve the case with user registration OP mentioned. (or does it?)

Comment: ssg, it does. I use the same technique in my website. Please be more specific about what exactly it doesn't solve.

Comment: @Jake The OP is asking about a way of redirecting the user after registering, not after login in.

Comment: The exact same principle works for any redirection you want.The routing code should be called in this case from the Register action. Anyway, this is a common need for both registration and login, so my code works for both.

Comment: @Jake I believe your approach assumes all the responsibility for what MembershipProvider normally does itself, and I think OP is asking about MembershipProvider. You know, you don't need to do anything about redirection when you use membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can save in the user's session the authorization page he wanted to see before redirection ... Request.Url.AbsoluteUri. Try using a Filter.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution to your problem is to pass the current url to query string from login page (in register link) like this;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Index", "Account", new { returnUrl Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null)
```

so, now you can catch this returnUrl like others in controller method parameter and you can then redirect user back to this returnUrl